# How to resolve Google drive conflicts manually?

Tags: google-drive

I refreshed my Windows PC but kept old files. Some old files hadn't synchronized with Google drive. It now notifies me, that it's going to make copies.

How can I replace the files from the cloud with local files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I posted this, I hoped that there would be a better solution, but eventually I:

1. Moved all local files form Google drive folder to another folder.
2. Synced Google drive with empty local folder, so it downloaded everything again.
3. Moved contents of local folder to google drive and overwrote downloaded files
4. Synced once more

Comment: Maybe fine for small size, but mine is like 90GB already

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to fix conflicts manually when GD copies the files and you don't know which ones.

Go to your google drive folder where it is installed.
Find the folder for your user.

> C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\user_default

There, find a file called: **sync_log.txt** and open it with notepad or any basic text editor like notepad.

Search for "**conflict**". It will find the lines where there was a conflict. You can see exactly which file was conflicting and what's the name of the new file

Example:

> 2017-10-16 13:17:22,721 +0200 WARNING pid=7180 1212:Worker-2
>   filename_manager.py:339 Filename truncated or found a conflict. 
>   Renaming u'\\?\D:\path...\google drive\**file.extension**' to
>   u'\\?\D:\path...\google drive\**file.extension (1).mel**'

Where file.extension is your file (thing.jpg)

Comment: Ok, you found it, now what? How does this fix it as you claimed?

Comment: I guess in the part they said "manually", @vanowm...